# Raise exception for error logs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using a library that is logging an error.  But I'd like it to raise an exception instead.

Is there quick way to have an exception raised instead of just an error being logged?

The library I'm using is `cssutils`, but for simplicity, suppose my code looks like:

```
from foo import do_something
do_something(x)
```

and suppose `do_something` will log an error if `x` was unacceptable input.  Is there some quick hack that would cause an exception to be raised if `do_something` logs an error?  Or is the only way to edit `foo`'s source?

Comment: Having some example code would be nice! Show where you want to raise an exception instead of logging

Comment: Well, modify the library so that it also throws exceptions after doing the logging...

Comment: @ChristopherApple, sorry, the question was unclear.  I've edited it.

Comment: @DanMašek, right, I edited the question to clarify.  Indeed modifying thje library would work but given I'm just doing a quick script, I was hoping for some clever 1-2 line hack ("all error logs now throw exceptions"), instead of having to look at the library source.

Comment: @Garrett :D Never hurts to look through the code. Took about 2 minutes to find this [ErrorHandler class](https://bitbucket.org/cthedot/cssutils/src/0825034be82bf1ea58911f11c231d7962f2a319b/src/cssutils/errorhandler.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)  Some more details [here in the docs](https://pythonhosted.org/cssutils/docs/logging.html). Seems like there's already support to throw instead of logging, you just need to enable it.

Comment: @DanMašek, thanks, that's very helpful and solves my problem!  I'm still interested, just of curiosity, if there was some quick hack in Python, but I'm gonna take the negative response to this question as a "nope, not possible".

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you want to still log the error, but you can try something like:

```
if error_is_true:
    raise Exception("error message...")
```

With log:

```
try: 
    my_function() 
except Exception:
    logger.exception("error msg...")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think my question was unclear.  I've edited it now.

Comment: That's better, cool. What should happen if your script logs an error? Should it keep running or an exception is raised and it stops? Regarding logging, have a look at this link:  https://www.loggly.com/blog/exceptional-logging-of-exceptions-in-python/

Comment: It should just raise and stop executing.